# Given the order of an unknown element in an unknown group, find the orders of other elements in the group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given an unknown group $G$, with an element $x \in G$ such that $o(x) = 18$. Find the orders of $x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^{12}$.

From my textbook, there is a theorem that states:
If $o(x)=n$ and $gcd(m,n)=d$, then $o(x^m)=n/d$.

Applying this to the first two parts of the problem gives:

$o(x) = 18$

$o(x^2) = \frac{18}{gcd(2,18)} = 9$

$o(x^3) = \frac{18}{gcd(3,18)} = 6$

However, the theorem is fairly general. Could it be interpreted to use the results of $o(x^2)$ as $n$ rather than the $o(x)$ given in the original problem?

For example,

$o(x) = 18$

$o(x^2) = \frac{18}{gcd(2,18)} = 9$

$o(x^3) = \frac{9}{gcd(3,9)} = 3$

Clearly, this is giving a different answer for $o(x^3)$. Is this supposed to be correct, or am I only supposed to use the original $o(x)$ for $n$?

Answer (score 1):

Since you take $o(x^2)=n$, your last computation is for $o((x^2)^3)=o(x^6)$, not $o(x^3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple, elementary observations make many things easy here.

- Order of an element is equal to the order of cyclic (sub)group generated by that element.
- If $k$ is relatively prime to order of $x$, then $x$ and $x^k$ generate same cyclic (sub)group, i.e. $<x>=<x^k>$

Suppose given $o(x)=n$. To find order of $x^m$ ($m\leq n$), write $m$ as product of two numbers, where one number divides $n$ and other is relatively prime to $n$:
$$m=dn', \mbox{where $d$ divides $n$ and $n'$ is relatively prime to $n$}.$$
(This is exactly what the gcd business in your arguments: $d$ is gcd of $m$ and $n$.)

Now how this simplifies the finding of order of $x^m$? Well! By two remarks above, 
$$o(x^m)=o(<x^m>)=o(<x^{dn'}>)=o(<({x^{n'})}^d>)=o(<x^d>)=o(x^d).$$
Since order of $x$ is $n$ and $d$ is a divisor of $n$, the order of $x^d$ must be $n/d$.

---

A small mistake in your last step: it should be 
$$o(x^3)=\frac{18}{gcd(3,18)}=6.$$